# Replace or append to link

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I am working on an old Sitecore 4 solution where i need to manipulate the output of a field slightly. I have a normal field (Message) that i am outputting via `<sc:html field="message"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Message',.)"/>`.

Either works just fine.

I now have to search in the "Message" field for links, and then i need to append the date to the end of the link like so "`<a href="http://www.thisismydomain.com?utm_campaign=01-01-2011">this is my link</a>`

How could i accomplish the above in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Icky icky if that's what it looks like and the message field contains escaped markup. If that's the case, you can't reliably do it. Much better to parse all your input and do the XSL processing on the full tree. Don't even think of regular expressions if you've tagged the question with @xslt.

Comment: The "Message" field is a Rich-text field in Sitecore.

Comment: Can you add an xsl extension method and do the processing there?

Comment: I have complete control over the xslt file and the whole solution, so i can basiclly do what ever?

Comment: Have you considered progressive enhancement on the client side using something like jQuery to append the date query to the links?

Comment: The problem is that it is for a html newsletter, so i can't really use JS to append/replace the html :-(

Comment: Noboby with further suggestions?

Comment: Well I wouldn't use XSLT for it... in my expirience it's just too slow when doing anything but basic retrieve data compared to a asp.net user control.

And in a user control, you can do some good old c# coding. Maybe using regex.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to do a find and convert urls to links.

I see these as your Options:
 1. Xpath 2.0 supports functions like matches and replace which use regular expressions. See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string or http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace. I'm not sure if sitecore supports Xpath 2.0. From memory i dont think it supports Xpath 2.0. If it does you are in luck and you can do something similar like this

```
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., 'http.*')">
              <strong><xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'http.*','REPLACED TEXT')"/></strong>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
```

1. Find and replace the Message values before or after it gets to XSL transformation just before you render the output.

Things to what out for:

1. Why do you have URLs without showing up as Links in Message tag? Is it a case where you are not using WYSIWYG for content?
2. If this seems to be too much work, which sounds like it is. You can have a workaround to have a javascript at the end of the page. Which will simply find and replace URLs to links. Make sure you don't double up. Regex is your friend here.